# CarouselView xamarin forms conflicting Xamarin forms error

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I have been working with `CarouselView` while using the Nuget Package `Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView`. I have tried to display the images as auto sliding.

**XAML**

```xml
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
    <cv:CarouselView x:Name="MainCarouselView" Position="{Binding PositionIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding .}"></Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </cv:CarouselView >
</StackLayout>
```

**C#**

```cs
var image = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>
{
    ImageSource.FromFile("Image1.jpg"),
    ImageSource.FromFile("Image2.jpg"),
    ImageSource.FromFile("Image3.jpg")
};

MainCarouselView.ItemsSource = image;

Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), (Func<bool>) (() =>
{
    MainCarouselView.Position = (MainCarouselView.Position + 1) % image.Count;
    return true;
}));
```

After running the app on the device or emulator I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS0433  The type 'CarouselView' exists in both
>   'Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

I have tried to delete the Nuget Package and tried then the `CarouselView` remains empty and it also does not contain the property of `Position`. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: I have solved using CarouselView.FormsPlugin
Xaml:

```
<controls:CarouselViewControl x:Name="MainCarouselView"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Position="{Binding PositionIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding .}"></Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
              </controls:CarouselViewControl >
```

And kept the cs code same. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: the library you are using is in preview, has stayed that way years and is not indented to be completed. Xamarin is going to have a new concept for carousel. if such a beta component is giving you issues you would recommend you don't use it. It might be easier to make your own component than tackling these issues

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I have resolved it using CarouselView.FormsPlugin. It worked perfect.

Comment: Ok then post an answer and still take what I said into consideration. Consider the possible issues you may face and the time each might take to fix. I once tried to use Carousel and after a series of issues resorted to using my own control

Answer (score 2):

Use CarouselView control for Xamarin Forms
https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

and be sure you are following these steps:

In your iOS and Android projects call:

MainActivity.cs :

```
CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Android.CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
```

AppDelegate.cs :

```
CarouselView.FormsPlugin.iOS.CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
```

On your XAML view

```
xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
```

Comment: Hi Motumo, I have resolved it with other plugin that I have mentioned in the edit. The CarouselView that has been coupled with Xamarin forms does not support position property as I have tried(not very sure though). But I have done it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You shoudn't use [Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView) plugin, as it's hasn't been updated for years...For those interested, it was supposed to be an optimised successor of the [CarouselPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page) - you can read more about it from James' [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/). For some reason it has been completely abandoned by Xamarin.Forms team.

[image: Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView Last Updated]

Currently the best solution is to use Alex's Rainman [CarouselView.FormsPlugin](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) plugin, which is just great! However, I think currently it has some issues with supporting Xamarin.Forms 3.5 ([github issue](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView/issues/489))

*NOTE*: Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you might want to have a look at the Sharpnado's [HorizontalListView](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms) carousel layout, which I'm almost certain is based off of the Alex's package.

For the future, keep an eye on the [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview), which will be a base for the brand new CarouselView in the Xamarin.Forms 4.0. You can read a bit more about it (and see a preview) in this [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-4-0-feature-preview-an-entirely-new-point-of-collectionview/)

*NOTE*: Please avoid using CarouselPage as well as the Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView

> The CarouselPage does not support UI virtualization. Therefore, performance may be affected if the CarouselPage contains too many child elements.

Comment: Hi @Ale_lipa, I have used this plugin to solve. The only problem that comes with this plugin is that it does not work inside StackLayout. I will mark your answer and I have also edited my question and included the XAML part which runs perfect.